# How to use registry scopes with Yarn 2.0 and Azure Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, yarnpkg, azure-artifacts, yarnpkg-v2

I would like to use https://registry.yarnpkg.com as my package registry for all packages except 1 that I am hosting on Azure Artifacts.

I have the following `.yarnrc.yml` file

```
yarnPath: ".yarn/releases/yarn-berry.js"    
npmScopese:
      my-scope:
        npmRegistryServer: 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<my-org>/_packaging/<my-feed>/npm/registry/'
        npmAlwaysAuth: true
        npmAuthIdent: 'my-auth-stuff'
```

then in the console I run
`yarn add @my-scope/my-package@1.0.0`

I get the following error
`@my-scope/my-package@npm:1.0.0: Response code 404 (Not Found)`

The following returns a 200 response

```
curl GET 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<my-org>/_packaging/<my-feed>/npm/registry/<my-package>' --header 'Authorization: <my-auth>'
```

Not sure if am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody who comes across this
I solved it by changed my package name to `@my-scope/my-package` in artifacts.